# Qemu - debug new syscall

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, qemu

as a school project I have to add a syscall to the latest stable linux kernel. I did and recompiled the kernel using `make defconfig` and `make`.

After going through several tutorials to boot the kernel (none of which worked), I finally found something [here](https://nostillsearching.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/compiling-linux-kernel-and-running-it-using-qemu/) (adapting it to x86_64 version of the kernel). This tutorial makes me create a initramfs using `mkinitramfs -o file`.

The problem is, I need to test my syscall on this new kernel but once I boot it I get redirected to a `(initramfs)` prompt, and I have no idea how to install packages, or if it is even the right solution.

My question -> how would I get gcc on this virtual machine so I can compile a simple C test program, run it and make sure my syscall works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if anyone wants to know how to do that, here's how I did it -> I compiled on my machine, created my own initramfs (following the instructions [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs) (don't gzip or qemu won't read it somehow)), put the executable in the initramfs before cpio it, then launched qemu and the executable, voila.

I know this is not the ideal solution, it only worked because both the kernel I was testing and my machine were linux x86_64, but I was out of options.

(If you want to pass gcc to your initramfs, don't, it segfaults when compiling).